# TCP multithreading

Tags: java, android, multithreading, tcp, tcpserver

Please have a look at the noobish code of mine below.
The intention is to create a server where multiple clients can join and send data constantly.

The works up to 3 clients with no errors, once the 4th client joins in during the three other have started to transfer data through the server freezes.

I dont have log or anything as the tablet completely frozen. Need to force close the app.

I guess it is caused one of the while(true) super solution i've got but cannot figure out why is it not happening earlier before the 4th client joins in.

SERVER:

```
public class TCPServer extends Thread implements Serializable {


Message receivedMessage = new Message();
ServerSocket serverSocket;
Socket socket;
ObjectInputStream ois;

public static ArrayList<Socket> ClientList = new ArrayList<>();

public void run() {
    try {

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);

        while(true)
        {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            ClientList.add(socket);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            Thread t = new Thread(new TCPComThread(socket,ois));
            t.start();
        }

    }catch (IOException ioe){
        try{
          socket.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {e.printStackTrace();
            ioe.printStackTrace();}

    }

}
```

And the TCPCOMTHREAD:

```
   class TCPComThread implements Runnable{
   private Socket client;
   private ObjectInputStream oisFromOutside;

   TCPComThread(Socket client, ObjectInputStream oisFromOutside)
   {
        this.client = client;
        this.oisFromOutside = oisFromOutside;
   }

    public void run(){

        MessageToServer obj_message_to_server;
        LessonToServer obj_lesson_to_server;

        try {

            Object aux;

            while(!client.isClosed()) {

                aux = oisFromOutside.readObject();
                if (aux instanceof LessonToServer) {
                    obj_lesson_to_server = (LessonToServer) aux;

                    //receivedMessage.obtain();
                    receivedMessage = new Message();
                    receivedMessage.obj = obj_lesson_to_server;
                    LessonToServerHandler.sendMessage(receivedMessage);

                }

                if (aux instanceof MessageToServer) {
                    obj_message_to_server = (MessageToServer) aux;

                    //receivedMessage.obtain();
                    receivedMessage = new Message();
                    receivedMessage.obj = obj_message_to_server;
                    MessageToServerHandler.sendMessage(receivedMessage);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

Can someone point out what could be causing the above issue?
Thanks

EDIT: I believe the above code is fine, after commenting out everything after the readobject it does not freeze. So the problem is probably with the handler.
HANDLER CODE:

```
private static Handler LessonToServerHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){

        LessonToServer obj = (LessonToServer) msg.obj;

       // SAVE THE IMAGE TO INTERNAL STORAGE

        Log.e("SCHOOLID",obj.SchoolID);
        Log.e("CHILDID",obj.ChildID);
        Log.e("LESSONNAME",obj.Lessonname);
        Log.e("LESSONNUMBER",obj.Lessonnumber);
        Log.e("RESULT",obj.Result);
        Log.e("ISJUNK",obj.IsJunk.toString());

        Bitmap bitmap = Coding.decodeBase64(obj.byteArray);

        Shared.Utils.saveToInternalStorage(bitmap,obj.SchoolID,obj.ChildID,obj.Lessonname,obj.Lessonnumber,obj.Result, ServerApplication.getAppContext(),obj.IsJunk);

    }
};
```

Comment: Maybe it because are you trying to access the  internal storage from out of the main thread?

Comment: @GabrielPereira thanks for your answer. I just wanted to edit again. Have commented out everything inside of the listener, so I have an empty listener only. Still freezes. Did comment out the call of the listener "//LessonToServerHandler.sendMessage(receivedMessage);" and voila, did not freeze. So the problem is with this call or how the handler is defined, but I am too noob to see the problem. Actually I am getting about 20-30 message a second. Is it possible that I am running out of handlers or something like that?

Comment: According with documentation you need to associate one handler for each thread, maybe the problem is the usage as static.

Comment: @GabrielPereira made it public only withouth being static, no success. Is there any way to define and call this handler from the thread?

Comment: According to the documentation you will need to instantiate the Handler in this case in the Server thread, and by statical reference (you can use a singleton) acquire the server instance inside children and run a method that will call the handle.
See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler and https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui#java.

Comment: @d4Mn I think you may be overloading your UI thread. Saving 20-30 bitmaps a second is a lot of work, and I assume your `Handler` was created on the UI thread. That means that all your "saving" work is going in the same message queue as your "UI work" (handling motion events, drawing views, and so forth). If there's a few hundred `receivedMessages` in the queue when you, say, tap the screen, it's going to take a while for the UI thread to get around to handling that tap! All those files have to be saved first. Make sense?

Comment: @d4Mn Why are your clients sending so many pictures, anyway? Is that  realistic? I would throttle the clients back a bit (well, _way_ back), and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: @greeble31 Thank you for your comment. I am developing an app for a special project where a tablet can have up to 30 clients joined to. The clients have their jobs to finish. Once they are finished they can send up to 55 images / job. In the case of 30 clients this is 1650 images. These images are not too big 200-300kbytes but theoretically a lot can arrive at the same time. I have found the same solution that you suggested by slowing down the sending but I just dont feel taht this is the righ solution.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case of "UI thread doing too much work" (based on the amount of "file-write" jobs that are being queued to the UI thread via `sendMessage()`).

So, how to fix it? It may be time to offload some work to a non-UI thread. Luckily, you already have several: Your `TCPComThreads`. Based on the code presented, you don't need to do the file-writes on the UI thread anyway. You could simply replace the `LessonToServerHandler.sendMessage()` call with your existing `handleMessage()` logic. Keeping this work on the `TCPComThread` has the added benefit that jobs will be completed just as quickly as they are received (they will "self-throttle", since each job must be written to disk before a new one can be received).